# Clear Screen Method in Python Not Working Properly

Tags: python, terminal, os.system

I'm working on a game and I have a function that prints the game board to the terminal every turn. I'm trying to use `os.system('cls')` to clear the screen before every time I print the board again.
I wrote the following function:

```
def clear_screen():
    # for windows
    if os.name == 'nt':
        _ = os.system('cls')

    # for mac and linux(here, os.name is 'posix')
    else:
        _ = os.system('clear')
```

But the method does not work properly work when I call it (I also tried using `os.system('cls')` straight instead of a function), it does not clear the terminal but instead, it prints a small arrow.

[image]

Note: I'm using JetBrains PyCharm IDE

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Are you running this from the Windows console or from an emulated console in an IDE?

Comment: I'm using JetBrains PyCharm IDE. I will add it to the question description :)

Comment: Run it from the true Windows console, this is a known issue with PyCharm's console I believe